# Junit test cases not running because of Two Jaxb context

Tags: spring-mvc, jaxb, spring-junit

I am using spring mvc.I have two jaxb context configured in my App-config.xml as follows.
Because of this i had issues running my project in Tomcat server.So we migrated to Liberty Was(8.0) server.Then it started working fine.

```
<bean id="jaxbContext" class="javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext" factory-method="newInstance">   
        <constructor-arg>     
            <list>        
                <value>com.xxx.aaa</value>     
            </list>   
        </constructor-arg> 
    </bean>     


    <bean id="jaxbContextnew" class="javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext" factory-method="newInstance">   
        <constructor-arg>     
            <list>        
                <value>com.xxx.bbb</value>     
            </list>   
        </constructor-arg> 
    </bean>
```

Now while running JUnit test cases with spring junit 4 runner I am getting following error.
Actually configuration is fine.
1)Please clarify what needs to be done to config two jaxb context.
 or
2)can we point to custom jaxb implementation while running juint alone?
 How to fine which jaxb context my web application is using?

```
TRACE DefaultListableBeanFactory - Ignoring factory method [public static javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(java.lang.String,java.lang.ClassLoader,java.util.Map) throws javax.xml.bind.JAXBException] of bean 'jaxbContextnew': org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'jaxbContextNew' defined in URL [file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring/app-config.xml]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [java.lang.String]: Could not convert factory method argument value of type [java.util.ArrayList] to required type [java.lang.String]: Failed to convert value of type 'java.util.ArrayList' to required type 'java.lang.String'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.util.ArrayList] to required type [java.lang.String]: no matching editors or conversion strategy found
TRACE DefaultListableBeanFactory - Ignoring factory method [public static javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(java.lang.String,java.lang.ClassLoader) throws javax.xml.bind.JAXBException] of bean 'jaxbContextNew': org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'jaxbContextNew' defined in URL [file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring/app-config.xml]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [java.lang.String]: Could not convert factory method argument value of type [java.util.ArrayList] to required type [java.lang.String]: Failed to convert value of type 'java.util.ArrayList' to required type 'java.lang.String'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.util.ArrayList] to required type [java.lang.String]: no matching editors or conversion strategy found
TRACE DefaultListableBeanFactory - Ignoring factory method [public static javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(java.lang.Class[],java.util.Map) throws javax.xml.bind.JAXBException] of bean 'jaxbContextNew': org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'jaxbContextNew' defined in URL [file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring/app-config.xml]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 1 of type [java.util.Map]: Ambiguous factory method argument types - did you specify the correct bean references as factory method arguments?
TRACE DefaultListableBeanFactory - Ignoring factory method [public static javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(java.lang.String) throws javax.xml.bind.JAXBException] of bean 'jaxbContextNew': org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'jaxbContextNew' defined in URL [file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring/app-config.xml]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [java.lang.String]: Could not convert factory method argument value of type [java.util.ArrayList] to required type [java.lang.String]: Failed to convert value of type 'java.util.ArrayList' to required type 'java.lang.String'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.util.ArrayList] to required type [java.lang.String]: no matching editors or conversion strategy found
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no constructor for a JAXBContext; you use a factory method. But if the `<constructor-arg>`element can be used for the factory method ǹewInstance`as well, please note that the argument is never an ArrayList. If you want to combine two packages in a single context, use the String value

```
"com.xxx.aaa:com.xxx.bbb"
```

as a simple String argument tothe constructor/factory method.

Comment: i tried this. but am getting following exception. Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 1 of type [java.lang.ClassLoader]: Ambiguous factory method argument types - did you specify the correct bean references as factory method arguments?

Comment: this is my changed config as you told.<constructor-arg>     
        
    <value type="java.lang.String">com.xxx.aaa:com.xxx.bbb</value>     
   
  </constructor-arg>

Comment: Did you ever manage to run this with a single package for the JAXB context, and if so, how? - I don't see anything that's wrong now, and the previous error most certainly is gone.